# assigning id values from values, not names, with purrr::map_dfr

Tags: r, purrr

I think this question is related to [Using map_dfr and .id for list names and list of list names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411260/using-map-dfr-and-id-for-list-names-and-list-of-list-names) but not identical ...

I often use `map_dfr` for a case where I want to use the *value* of each argument, not its *name*, as the `.id` variable. Here's a silly example: I am computing the mean of `mtcars$mpg` raised to the second, fourth, and sixth power:

```r
library(tidyverse)
list(2,4,6) %>% map_dfr(~tibble(x=mean(mtcars$mpg^.)), .id="name")
##   name           x
##   <chr>      <dbl>
## 1 1           439.
## 2 2        262350.
## 3 3     198039783.
```

I would like the `name` variable to be 2, 4, 6 instead of 1, 2, 3.  I can hack this by including `setNames(.data)` in the pipeline:

```r
list(2,4,6) %>% 
   setNames(.data) %>% 
   map_dfr(~tibble(x=mean(mtcars$mpg^.)), .id="name")
```

but I wonder if there is a more idiomatic approach I'm missing?

---

As for the suggestion of using something like `~ tible(name=., ...)`: nice, but *slightly* less convenient for the case where the mapping function already returns a tibble, because we have to add an otherwise unnecessary `tibble()` call:

```r
list(2, 4, 6) %>%   
    map_dfr(~ tibble(name=., 
       broom::tidy(lm(mpg~cyl, data=mtcars, offset=rep(., nrow(mtcars))))))
```

Comment: Why not just `list(2, 4, 6) %>% 
 map_dfr(~ tibble(x = mean(mtcars$mpg^.x),
                  names = .x))`?

Comment: that works (you can post it as an answer and I will at least upvote) but my example was possibly too simple: there are plenty of cases where the returned object is already a tibble and I don't want to add another `tibble()` statement ...

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is your aim, but for the updated question, you could just do `list(2, 4, 6) %>%   
 map_dfr(~ broom::tidy(lm(mpg~cyl, data=mtcars, offset=rep(., nrow(mtcars)))) %>%
          mutate(names = .x))`.

Comment: fair enough. Then the `names` column will be last, though ... (there is [lots of discussion](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2047) about how/whether we can easily make `mutate` add variables at the beginning/on the left ...)

Answer (score 4):

OK, I think I found this shortly before posting (so I'll answer). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951080/can-lists-be-created-that-name-themselves-based-on-input-object-names/16951524#16951524) points out that `tibble::lst()` is a self-naming list function, so as long as we use `tibble::lst(2,4,6)` instead of `list(2,4,6)`, it Just Works, e.g.

```r
lst(2,4,6) %>% map_dfr(~tibble(x=mean(mtcars$mpg^.)), .id="name")
```

Answer (score 3):

This can work too:

```r
library(tidyverse)

#@ben Bolker answer.
lst(2,4,6) %>% map_dfr(~tibble(x=mean(mtcars$mpg^.)), .id="power")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   power          x
#>   <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1 2           439.
#> 2 4        262350.
#> 3 6     198039783.

list(2, 4, 6) %>% map_df(~ tibble(power = as.character(.x) , x = mean(mtcars$mpg^.)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   power          x
#>   <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1 2           439.
#> 2 4        262350.
#> 3 6     198039783.

#another option
seq(2, 6, 2) %>%  map2_df(rerun(length(.), mtcars$mpg), ~ c(x = as.character(.x), mean = round(mean(.y^.x), 0)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   x     mean     
#>   <chr> <chr>    
#> 1 2     439      
#> 2 4     262350   
#> 3 6     198039783
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This is also possible, however it would not have been my first choice and only a `map` would suffice:

```
library(purrr)

list(2, 4, 6) %>%
  pmap_dfr(~ tibble(power = c(...), x = map_dbl(c(...), ~ mean(mtcars$mpg ^ .x))))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  power          x
  <dbl>      <dbl>
1     2       439.
2     4    262350.
3     6 198039783.
```

Comment: works for the simple example I gave (should have included the more complex example up front ...)

Comment: Yes it is just possible not at all the best. This would've been my first choice had a similar one would not have been posted earlier: 
`list(2, 4, 6) %>%
  map_dfr(~ tibble(name = .x, x = mean(mtcars$mpg^.x)))` .
But it would be nice to take a look at a piece of the original data set.